# p-footer is not a known element error in p-dialog

Tags: angular, primeng

> in html

```
<p-dialog [resizable]="false" header="Softcopy Acceptance for Ledger and 
Invoice" [(visible)]="!displaySoftCopyDialog"
[responsive]="true" showEffect="fade" [modal]="true" [width]="600">

<p style="margin: 5px; height: 305px"><span>
<span style="color:red;">GO GREEN</span><br>
Season’s Greetings! <br>
copy, they may consciously opt for the Hardcopy option.<br><br>
We wish for your consent to join us in this drive by opting for monthly 
bills through E-bill only.
</span></p>
<p-footer>
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn_searchSmall_add" 
(click)="remindSoftCopy()">Remind Later</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn_searchSmall_add" 
(click)="acceptSoftCopy()">Accept</button>
</div>
 </p-footer>
</p-dialog>
```

> in ts file i seted these 2 from primeng

```
DialogModule,
SharedModule
```

> in module also i seted these 2 from primeng

```
DialogModule,
SharedModule
```

> why this happens

Answer (score 0):

What version of prime NG are you using in the package.json file? Older libraries (1.*.*) don't support p-footer and p-header, it was included since version 2.

Comment: If you want to use the 1.*.* change the p-footer to just footer, it should work.